# How to join two tables with max value not greater than another value of column

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Apologies for the confusing question title, but I'm not exactly sure how to describe the issue at hand.

I have two tables in Oracle 9i:

```
Pricing
-------
SKU
ApplicableTime
CostPerUnit

Inventory
---------
SKU
LastUpdatedTime
NumberOfUnits
```

`Pricing` contains incremental updates to the costs of each particular SKU item, at a specific Unix time. For example, if I have records:

```
SKU    ApplicableTime    CostPerUnit
------------------------------------
12345  1000              1.00
12345  1500              1.50
```

, then item 12345 is $1.00 per unit for any time between 1000 and 1500, and $1.50 for any time after 1500.

`Inventory` contains SKU, last updated time, and number of units.

What I'm trying to do is construct a query such that for each row in `Inventory`, I join the two tables based on SKU, I find the largest value for `Pricing.ApplicableTime` that is NOT greater than `Inventory.LastUpdatedTime`, get the `CostPerUnit` of that particular record from `Pricing`, and calculate `TotalCost = CostPerUnit * NumberOfUnits`:

```
SKU    TotalCost
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12345  (CostPerUnit at most recent ApplicableTime <= LastUpdatedTime)*NumberOfUnits
12346  <same>
...    ...
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM
  (select  p.SKU,
  p.ApplicableTime,
  p.CostPerUnit*i.NumberOfUnits as cost,
  row_number over (partition by p.SKU order by p.ApplicableTime desc) as rnk
  from Pricing p
  join  
  Inventory i on (p.sku = i.sku and i.LastUpdatedTime > p.ApplicableTime)
  )
where rnk=1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select SKU, i1.NumberOfUnits * p1.CostPerUnit as TotalCost
from Inventory i1, 
join (
    select SKU, max(ApplicableTime) as ApplicableTime, max(i.LastUpdatedTime) as LastUpdatedTime
    from Pricing p
    join Inventory i on p.sku = i.sku
    where p.ApplicableTime < i.LastUpdatedTime
    group by SKU
) t  on i1.sku = t.sku and i1.LastUpdatedTime = t.LastUpdatedTime
join Pricing p1 on p1.sku = t.sku and p1.ApplicableTime = t.ApplicableTime
```